# How to display a PickerView row content into a label

Tags: ios, swift, label, datasource, uipickerview

I'm new in Swift! and I'm learning from several sources.
I'm building a small app with only 2 elements ( PickerView and label )
I want to know how to let the PickerView row contents to be displayed into a label?
also is there a way to show more information for the row content?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
 
    @IBOutlet var picker: UIPickerView!
    
    let names = ["Sara", "Ali", "Joy"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        picker.dataSource = self
        picker.delegate = self
    }


}
 
extension ViewController : UIPickerViewDataSource {
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return names.count
    }
    
    
    
}
extension ViewController : UIPickerViewDelegate {
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return names[row]
    }
    
    
}
```

For example : when Ali is chosen, I want to display "He scores 90" in the label
but I don't want the "He scores 90" sentence to be shown next to Ali in PickerView itself

Thank you

Comment: Hint: Use one of the delegate methods for `UIPickerView`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and review [ask]. Your first step should be searching... a quick google search for `swift uipickerview tutorial` finds exactly what you need.

Comment: I did look through Google, but I didn’t work with my code

Answer (score 0):

Thank you El Tomato for your hint
it's one of the delegate methods - didSelectRow
and it worked great

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
 
    @IBOutlet var picker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
    
    let names = ["Sara", "Ali", "Joy"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        picker.dataSource = self
        picker.delegate = self
    }


}
 
extension ViewController : UIPickerViewDataSource {
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return names.count
    }
    
   
    
}
extension ViewController : UIPickerViewDelegate {
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return names[row]
       
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        label.text = names[row]
    }
    
    
    
}
```